# Change bootstrap modal tabs from dropdown menu (same page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to change tabs from the dropdown menu for my bootstrap tabs on the same page.

Here's the dropdown menu code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#day">Day</a></li>
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#night">Night</a></li>
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#drinks">Joogid</a></li>
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#takeaway">Takeaway</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the jQuery, where I'm trying to get rid of the /menuu/ that is in the link aswell with replaceing it with nothing.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.menu-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var str = this.href;
         this.href = str.replace('/menuu/', '');
        $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
    })
});
</script>
```

My code isn't unfortunately working. Any advice why?

Comment: Could you please add `tabs` html code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you..

```js
  $('.menu-link').each(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace( /\/menuu\//gi, '' ) );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#day">Day</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#night">Night</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#drinks">Joogid</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu-link" href="/menuu/#takeaway">Takeaway</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use regular expressions? `String.replace` should work just fine (he has only one occurrence of the string that he wants to replace).